# Universal Set & Axiom of Separation:

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Checking **Page 9, Theorem 3** of https://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/99015/mod_resource/content/1/320lecturenotes.pdf

It states that if a there exists a set of all sets i.e. $\exists x \forall y |y\in x$ then by the Axiom of Separation, the collection $\{y: y \in x \land y \notin y\}=R$ exists.

I don't understand how we derive the Russel Set from the premises that the set of all sets exist, and the Axiom of Seperation.

Comment: I’m afraid that I don’t understand what the problem is: the definition of $R$ that you give in the question is precisely an application of Separation to the universal set $x$ and the formula $\varphi(y)$ given by $y\notin y$.

Comment: What I don't understand is how our choice of $\varphi (y)  = y \notin y $ follows from defining the set of all sets $∃x∀y|y∈x$

Comment: Call your "set of all sets $S$". Then $R=\{y\in S:y\notin y\}$.

Comment: @Joeseph123: It doesn’t. We’re at liberty apply Separation to any formula, and we choose that one.

Comment: Write the [Separation Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement) and instantiate it with $V = \{ x \mid x=x \}$ as $A$ and with formula $y \notin y$ as $\varphi$.